# Convert number of days since Jan 1 2000 into date format

Tags: r, date, data-conversion

I have a column in my data as a number of days since Jan 1, 2000 (this is 0 day). How can I convert day number into date format (2000-01-01)?

```
Number_of_days    Date
3536              2011-01-03
3537              2011-01-04
3538              2011-01-05
3539              2011-01-06
3540              2011-01-07
3541              2011-01-08
```

I want to add a new column called `Date` similar to above one into my *df*. Number of days to Date above is just an example.

Comment: `as.Date(0, origin = '2000-01-01')`

Comment: `as.Date('2000/01/01') + df$Number_of_days`

Comment: @RuiBarradas nope "/" is just as fine.

Comment: @Sotos code worked but I had to add (minus 1) at the end to get the correct days. "/" is OK, gave me desired outcome.

Comment: Ahh...ok. Because you want January first as day 0...not day 1. Got it. Glad I could help

Comment: @Sotos Never have guessed it but it does work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need the `origin`-parameter of `as.Date`. Using:

```
as.Date(3536:3541, origin = '2000-01-01')
```

gives:

> ```
> [1] "2009-09-06" "2009-09-07" "2009-09-08" "2009-09-09" "2009-09-10" "2009-09-11"
> ```

---

In your case you can use:

```
as.Date(df$Number_of_days - 1, origin = '2000-01-01')
```

or:

```
as.Date(df$Number_of_days, origin = '1999-12-31')
```

Comment: This includes 2000-01-01 in my new column which shifts all conversion a cell down. But it converts the days. Thanks

Comment: @ZmnakoAwrahman I just included the zero to show the working of the function; I've updated the answer now

Comment: Thanks. Instead of writing the number of days range, I just select the column and minus one because 2000-01-01 is day ZERO. This code worked for me `as.Date(df$Number_of_days, origin = '2000-01-01') -1`

Comment: @ZmnakoAwrahman or `as.Date(df$Number_of_days - 1, origin = '2000-01-01')` or `as.Date(df$Number_of_days, origin = '1999-12-31')`, I've also updated the answer